# How do I make a TrieMap serializable in Scala?

Tags: scala, serialization

I know how to make a class serializable like this:

```
@SerialVersionUID(42L)
class foo extends Serializable {
    val bar = scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Int, Map[String, Any]]()
}
```

But what if I just want to make a variable serializable, in this case, just `bar`?
How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't; what would that even mean? Most of the builtin types (e.g. `TrieMap`) are already serializable. Did you try just... serializing it?

Comment: Ah, yes. That works! Apologies for the lame question.

Comment: @lmm: I think you can go ahead, and turn your comment into an answer. Would be helpful.